# f is $C^1$ and decreasing then $\int_1^{\infty}f(x)\sin(x)dx$ converges.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing and continuously differentiable with $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)= 0$. Then
$$\int_1^{\infty}f(x)\sin(x)dx$$ converges.

MY attempt:

for $\epsilon >0$ choose $d \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $|f(x)| < \epsilon /2  \hspace{3mm}\forall x \geq d$
Using integration by parts we have 
$\int_1^df(x)\sin(x)dx = f(1)\cos(1) - f(d)\cos(d) +  \int_1^df'(x)\cos(x)dx$

since $f'(x) <0$ we will have

$|\int_1^df'(x)\cos(x)dx| < \int_1^d (-f'(x))dx = f(1) - f(d)< f(1) +\epsilon/2$

Therefore we have 
$|\int_1^df(x)\sin(x)dx |\leq  |f(1)\cos(1) - f(d)\cos(d)| + |f(1) +\epsilon/2| < 2 |f(1) +\epsilon/2|  $

Here I have shown that the integral is bounded.

**My question is** does the boundedness implies convergence of integral? If not then what can be added.

Comment: $\int_\pi^\infty f(x) \sin x \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x) \sin x \, dx$ and the sum converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: How Alternating test?. Also can you help me with my end question that whether boundedness of integral implies convergence of integral?

Comment: No, boundedness of partial integrals does not imply convergence in general - for example, $\int_0^R \sin x \, dx$ is bounded but $\int_0^\infty \sin x \, dx$ does not converge.  But to correct the argument - if you show that $\int_a^b f(x) \sin x \, dx \to 0$ as $a, b \to \infty$ then that implies the partial integrals are Cauchy, so completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ would imply the integral converges.

Comment: Wouldn't then continuity be sufficient, instead of having $f$ be continuously differentiable? With the decreasing and 'zero at infinity' properties still holding, that is.

Comment: In fact, not even continuity is needed for the alternating series test: if $a_n := \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x) \sin x \, dx$ then $a_n$ is alternating in sign, $|a_n|$ is decreasing, and $a_n \to 0$.  (And also, $f$ decreasing implies $f$ has at most countably many discontinuities, so it's locally Riemann integrable.)

Answer (score 4):

Boundedness does not imply convergence.  Take the simple example of $f\equiv 1$.  Then, we have

$$\int_1^L f(x)\sin(x)\,dx=\cos(1)-\cos(L)$$

which fails to converge as $L\to \infty$.

To show convergence, we use the Cauchy Criterion for convergence to analyze the integral $\int_{u}^{v}f(x)\sin(x)\,dx$, where $1\le u<v$.

Using the Bonnet form of the second mean value theorem, we have for some number $\xi \in [u,v]$

$$\left|\int_u^vf(x)\sin(x)\,dx\right|=f(u) \left|\int_u^\xi \sin(x)\,dx\right|\le 2f(u)$$

Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, we choose a number $N$ so large that $|f(u)|<\epsilon/2$, for $N<u<v$.  And for such an $N$ we see that

$$\left|\int_u^vf(x)\sin(x)\,dx\right|<\epsilon$$

Inasmuch as the conditions for the Cauchy Criterion are satisfied, the given integral converges.

---

**NOTE:**

There was nothing particularly special about the sine function in the development other than the fact that its integral, $\int_1^v \sin(x)\,dx$, is bounded for all $v\ge 1$.

Comment: Please explain this: $$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(x)\sin(x)dx=f(n\pi)\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin(x)dx$$

Comment: I think that should actually be: for some $x_n \in [n \pi, (n+1) \pi]$, $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x) \sin x \, dx = f(x_n) \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \sin x \, dx$.

Comment: I've modified the proof.